# Problems with WEBDAV on lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, webdav

I've setup webdav on lighttpd but I'm getting a  Cannot open collection - 404 not found when I try to access the share through cadaver. My lines for the vhost and share are as follows:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.markmhart.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/servers/www.markmhart.com/pages/" 
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/download/" {
    dir-listing.activate = "enable" 
  }
alias.url = ("/media" => "/media/mark/media")
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/media($|/)" {
        webdav.activate = "enable"
        webdav.is-readonly = "disable"
        webdav.sqlite-db-name = "/var/run/lighttpd/lighttpd.webdav_lock.db"

}
}
```

The path and files are good. They are chown to nobody:nogroup and are set to 755.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK.  I took out everything but the webdav.activate statement and now I'm getting a 405 Method not allowed.  Am I going backward?

Comment: Based on the config you have shared, you'll get 405 Method Not Allowed if you try a PROPFIND against https://www.markmhart.com .   Instead, you should access/mount https://www.markmhart.com/media/  Note that some WebDAV *clients* might expect the root "/" to be fully WebDAV accessible, so you might also try with another WebDAV client.